# Vyatta 6.2 IPv6 DNS handout

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, vyatta, radvd

I have a Vyatta server which I have connected to Hurricane Electric. I have setup the RADVD on the box and my LAN clients get a public global IPv6 address and route through the Vyatta box.

Where do I put my DNS server config though...? Nothing I seem to try will make it come to the clients with their addresses. I would like to be able to assign only IPv6 network info to my clients (no IPv4) for some testing, but then I cannot resolve names.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your /etc/radvd.conf enter this:

```
interface eth# {

    ...

    #DNS servers go here:
    RDNSS dead::beef beef::dead
    {
    };
}
```

If that isn't clear, there are no contents to the "RDNSS" section, but you do need to create the curly braces. The parameters to the section are `dead::beef` and `beef::dead` and those are what your clients will receive as DNS servers.

Alternatively, you can deploy DHCPv6 to obtain the other half of the IPv6 LAN 'equation' and inform clients of certain other properties of the network, such as DNS servers.

Comment: Both options work. Win7 doesn't seem to like either however. I believe this to be a shortfall on Windows behalf :(

Comment: This is exactly what we use in our Windows network. Are there any group policies that would be inhibiting IPv6 use on your network? You may want to check that. You may also have to check the firewall, we have DirectAccess deployed so there are a number of opened ports to enable that, such as everything in the "Core Networking" group in the Windows Firewall—Router Advertisement, Router Solicitation, etc. We've explicitly allowed those.